# Store last cell values of all sheets in one single sheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub WS()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Mar In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Mar.Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address(False, False)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next Mar
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

So how do I call the values it one go ? 
I have 10 different sheets and I want to pull the address of last cell of 10 different sheets.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the answer I suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.  Your question is a little unclear because you refer to both the last cell's `Address` (*I want to pull the address of last cell*) but also you mention something about `Value` (*how do I call the values*).  The code above will retrieve the `Address` of the last cell but also includes code to retrieve the values, you just have to comment out the one line and uncomment the other line.

```
Sub LastCellAddresses()
    Dim Mar As Worksheet
    Dim myValues As Variant
    Dim i As Integer: i = 1

    '## Create an Array with one item for each worksheet
    ReDim myValues(1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

    '## iterate the worksheets and add values to the array
    For Each Mar In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        '## Use one of these, depending on what you're trying to do.
        ' This line returns the ADDRESS
        myValues(i) = Mar.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address
        ' OR this line returns the VALUES
        'myValues(i) = Mar.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Value
        i = i + 1
    Next Mar

    '## Print each value from the array in its own row, from
    '   the activeCell
    '   Modify as needed
    ActiveCell.Resize(UBound(myValues)).Value = Application.Transpose(myValues)

End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't `.Address` be `.Value`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout depends on what you want to achieve, but I read this: "I want to pull the address of last cell".

Comment: + 1 True :) I read the title :D "Store last cell values of all sheets in one single sheet"

Comment: @SiddharthRout I made a revision, because after re-reading the question I am unsure whether OP wants the values or the address. Thanks!